# kiip integration in android

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate kiip in my android app . I have downloaded the latest sdk and sample example from https://kiip.me/ developers site . Also ,I have created a new app in kiip.me site.

Everything is fine but the problem is , I am getting KPResource null so showing No Promo . 
Here is the listner that I am using in **onStart()** method:

```
 public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            // The Activity context has been created by now, so start a new session.
            KPManager.getInstance().startSession(mStartSessionListener);
        } 

 private KPRequestListener<KPResource> mStartSessionListener = new KPRequestListener<KPResource>() {

        public void onFinished(KPManager manager, KPResource response) {
            if (response != null) {
                toast("Start Session Finished w/ Promo");
            } else {
                toast("Start Session Finished No Promo");
            }
            manager.showResource(response);

            // Start retrieving user's location
            new LocationHelper(ExampleApplication.this).requestLocationUpdates(mLocationListener);
        }
```

Here the response is always null , so getting the message :  **Start Session Finished No Promo**  . If anyone  has got similar problem then please share your views.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, can you share your code to integrate Kiip in Android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the issue has been resolved. I think the problem was with my device , when I tested it next day with some  other device, It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled promos for test devices in the dashboard on https://kiip.me?

It sounds like it could be a settings issue on the server side. Try logging in and switching promo frequency and adding your test device.